# Hyperledger Fabric - Peer unable to join channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

We are getting an error while trying a peer node to join a channel. Both members have separate peer nodes and separate EC2 machines acting as clients for the network. Member1 has created a channel and joined its peer node to the channel. Member2 has pulled the genesis block from their client but when trying to join the channel, we get the error:

`Error: genesis block file not found open ourchannel.block: no such file or directory`

despite seeing ourchannel.block in the directory we run the command. The command we're using to join the channel is:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true" \
-e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem" \
-e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=$PEER" \
-e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$MSP" \
-e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$MSP_PATH" \
cli peer channel join -b ourchannel.block \
-o $ORDERER --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
```

Comment: There is a ourchannel.block file in-place?

Answer (score 0):

You only have the genesis block (the file with `.block` extension) if you create a channel in a separate container, which is `cli` container in your case. Please check by using `ls` command inside the `cli` container.

A simple command to jump into `cli` container:

```
docker exec -it cli bash
```

Just in case you can't find genesis block, you can get it from the orderer (remember to modify the path to the cafile fit your project):

```
peer channel fetch 0 ourchannel.block -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c ourchannel --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

After this, you can join the channel with `peer channel join` command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I mentioned in the post, member2 was able to pull the genesis block. I didn't mention it, but I pulled it using the fetch command as you said.

Comment: Where did you locate the genesis block? in the container of `member2` or inside `cli` container? If you fetch the genesis inside `member2` container, you can not call join channel inside `cli` container

Comment: ahh, you solved your problem. The reason is the default path when `docker exec` run is something like this: `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer`. That's why it shows not found. Glad that you solved the prob.

Answer (score 0):

Simple issue, we had to specify the absolute path to the block file.

Instead of

`cli peer channel join -b ourchannel.block`

we used

`cli peer channel join -b /opt/home/ourchannel.block \`

and it worked.